# How to know about automatic installations in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd

I have a Centos release 6.7 server where I have installed Apache 2.4. The server came with Apache 2.2 but I have upgraded it to Apache 2.4.

From time to time, the system goes back to use Apache 2.2 and I don't know why.

For example, today, I realized that all of my sites were down. So I checked httpd status and it was stopped and it could not start because of a syntax error in `httpd.conf` file.

By using `which` command, I found that the httpd in use was at `/usr/sbin` folder, and in fact, `/etc/init.d/httpd` file contained this:

```
apachectl=/usr/sbin/apachectl
httpd=${HTTPD-/usr/sbin/httpd}
```

That is wrong, since my Apache 2.4 installation is at `/opt/apache`. So, to solve the problem, I changed those lines to be:

```
apachectl=/opt/apache/bin/apachectl
httpd=${HTTPD-/opt/apache/bin/httpd}
```

And system started to use Apache 2.4 again.

The question is, how can I check which automatic installations were carried out, and how can I avoid this to happen again in the future?

By the way, when I used `/usr/sbin/httpd -V` to get Apache information, it shows that it was built on last May 11th.

Comment: Check "/var/log/yum.log" to see if httpd 2.2 is being updated; Maybe you should remove old 2.2 httpd first, actually you don't use it, right?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6.x ships with Apache 2.2 (httpd-2.2) which would periodically get updated via yum. It appears that you are running a different version than what came with CentOS (as it is under /opt). Normally if the system was configured with httpd it will try to restart it after any updates. You can verify this by running the command: grep -i httpd /var/log/yum.log and seeing when it was updated or: rpm -qa -last | grep -i httpd. This should tell you when it was last updated and you can correlate your outage to these times.

It it probably best to remove the http-2.2 if you know you no longer need this and run the version under /opt.

Comment: When using that grep command, it in fact shows that the last update was on May 17th. That version of Apache is not used I think, since the active httpd is version 2.4. How can I uninstall all Apache 2.2? or do I have to go for each installed package? if that is the case, there is a package corresponding to each installed version, so I think I cannot proceed that way.

Comment: Yes - you should be able to remove the older httpd 2.2 version, one way would be to run:  yum erase httpd  or  yum erase <the full RPM name and version>  This will remove the package (and any dependencies), you will not have to worry about the older versions (they are upgraded as newer RPMs and installed). Verify you are not using any dependency package before removing them (yum will ask before removing).